# GitLab CI/CD fails when checking out a second repository on the same GitLab Server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab CI/CD script that creates a docker image and tags with $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

I then want to update a second repository on the same GitLab server which holds kubernetes manifests and update image tag in deployment.yaml

The job is failing in GitLab CI/CD with the following error

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.1 (674e0e29)
  on shell-runner 6mWoQLxUU, system ID: s_fbcc5c123da4
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on build...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/6mWoQLxUU/0/soxprox/projects/chat/chat-api/.git/
Checking out ae4a6daf as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ git config --global user.email "ci@soxprox.com"
$ rm -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ git config --global user.name "CI"
$ cat $PRIVATE_KEY > ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
$ git clone git@192.168.100.179:soxprox/projects/chat/chat-api-manifest.git
Cloning into 'chat-api-manifest'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $NEXUS_USERNAME -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD https://registry.lab.soxprox.com
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:latest .
    - docker push registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:latest
    - docker build -t registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - git config --global user.email "ci@soxprox.com"
    - rm -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - git config --global user.name "CI"
    - cat $PRIVATE_KEY > ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    - git clone git@192.168.100.179:soxprox/projects/chat/chat-api-manifest.git
    # Change the image tag in deployment.yaml file to the current commit ref name
    - sed -i.back "/image:/s/:[0-9].*/:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/g" docker-compose.yaml
    - git add .
    - git commit -m “Update image tag to $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME”
    - git push origin main
```

`$PRIVATE_KEY` is a file type variable which holds a SSH Private key. The public key has been added to GitLab

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following CI/CD Code

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $NEXUS_USERNAME -p $NEXUS_PASSWORD https://registry.lab.soxprox.com
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:latest .
    - docker push registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:latest
    - docker build -t registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA .
    - docker push registry.lab.soxprox.com/chat/chat-api:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - shell
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    # Add SSH key to root
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.100.179 > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    # Git
    - git config --global user.name "ci"
    - git config --global user.email "ci@soxprox.com"
    - git clone --single-branch --branch main git@192.168.100.179:soxprox/projects/chat/chat-api-manifest.git
    - cd chat-api-manifest
    # use sed to replace chat-api:xxxxx with chat-api:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - sed -i "s/chat-api:.*/chat-api:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/g" deployment.yaml
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "Update deployment image tag to $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - git push origin main
```